# I want to use paginator by using class based view on django

Tags: django, pagination, django-class-based-views

As I mentioned at Title I want to use paginator.
I coded as Django Docs introduced but it's not work.
What is the reason??

This is my View

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, UpdateView, DetailView
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from .models import Article

class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article

    def listing(request):
        article_list = Article.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(article_list, 7)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            articles = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            articles = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render_to_response('blog/article_list.html', {'articles': articles})
```

and the following is my urls

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from .views import ArticleCreateView, ArticleUpdateView, ArticleListView, ArticleDetailView
urlpatterns = patterns('',

                      url(r'^list/$', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='list'),

                       )
```

the last is my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} list {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <p>
        <a href="{% url "blog:create" %}">new</a>
    </p>

    {% for article in article_list %}
        <div id="article">
            <div id="author">
                <p>{{ article.author }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="time">
                <p>{{ article.created }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="body">
                <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="edit"> 
                <a href="{% url "blog:edit" article.pk  %}"> modify </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for article in articles %}
        {{ article.full_name|upper }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

        <div class="pagination">
            <span class="step-links">
                {% if articles.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page={{ articles.previous_page_number }}">pre</a>
                {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ articles.number }} of {{ articles.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>

                {% if articles.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ contacts.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}

            </span>

        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

what is problem??
I think server cannot dectect def listing in class based view

Comment: Are you aware pagination is built into `ListView`?https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginate_by

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita Yes! I aware of it but I want to know why this code doesn't work.

Comment: I presume because your method is named `listing`, and isn't called by anyhing. dispatch calls `get` or `post`, not `listing`.

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita Oh! I see!.Then what should I do? to call listing